# css hover div1.img1 affect on another div2.img2

Tags: html, css, hover

css hover `div1.img1` affect on another `div2.img2`

```css
.img1:hover + .i1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<article>

  <div class="bigimg">
    <img id="hauptimg" class="i4" style="position: absolute" src="imgs/k2.jpg" width="394px" height="309px">
    <img id="hauptimg" class="i3" style="position: absolute" src="imgs/k1.jpg" width="394px" height="309px">
    <img id="hauptimg" class="i2" style="position: absolute" src="imgs/big.jpg" width="394px" height="309px">
    <img id="hauptimg" class="i1" style="position: absolute" src="imgs/big2.jpg" width="394px" height="309px">
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="smallimg">
    <img id="secondimg" class="img1" src="http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/5f6a5a-1467583787.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    <br>
    <img id="secondimg" class="img2" src="http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/fd6130-1467583927.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    <br>
    <img id="secondimg" class="img3" src="http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/a2888b-1467583968.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>

</article>
```

[image]

with `+`, `>`, `~`  not working

Comment: You can't have duplicate IDs, use secondimg and hauptimg as classes and img1.../i1... as IDs

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS. The two elements are in completely separate parents. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators for what you can do with relationship combinators in CSS.

Comment: .img1:hover + .i1 means that .l1 is the next sibling of .img1, In you markup the next sibling is a <br>...